# theoretic difference between shallow copies and occurrences?

Tags: copy, theory, deep-copy, computation-theory, shallow-copy

Suppose I have:

```
a = MyClass()
my_list = [a,[a,[a]]]
```

From a theoretical point of view, we should say that `my_list[1][1][0]`, `my_list[1][0]` and `my_list[0]` are 'shallow copies' or just 'occurrences' of the same object? What would be the correct term?